# Can't push to heroku after accidentally deleting app on heroku

Tags: git, heroku

1) I was poking around heroku and accidentally delete my heroku app.

2) I ran heroku create and got this:

```
heroku create
Your version of git is 2.1.2. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
Creating polar-cove-4803... done, stack is cedar-14
https://polar-cove-4803.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/polar-cove-4803.git
```

3) After running heroku create, I ran this command:

```
git push heroku master
remote: !   No such app as murmuring-dawn-5953.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-dawn-5953.git/' not found
```

4) How do I reset the heroku remote and delete this remote so that when I do

```
git push heroku master
```

it pushes to the correct remote?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change the `heroku` remote to the new project's git URL

```
git remote set-url heroku https://git.heroku.com/polar-cove-4803.git
```

That will set your remote to your new project and you should be able to

```
git push heroku master
```